# Error when deploying to build host from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I get the following error when trying to deploy my Xamarin iOS application from Visual Studio to the build host on my mac. It builds fine when i do a Build>Build Solution...

```
1>Remote build step failed.

1>Done building target "_BuildNativeApplication" in project MyProject.Touch.csproj" -- FAILED.

1>Done building project "MyProject.Touch.csproj" -- FAILED.

1>Build FAILED.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I have tried completely reinstalling Xamarin on the Mac to no avail.

Comment: What build targets you set? And also please check you build configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually got this solved.

An incorrectly named screen in my iPhone storyboard was causing the error.